# Searching for non-common phrases with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, search, phrases

Is it possible to obtain results for non-common phrases (such as URLs for example) ?

I tried to encode my phrases. I used PHP urlencode() function to try to look for posts containing 'http://www.google.com'

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&type=post
```

however all I get is:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Comment: The URL you provide do return a bunch of results with paging...

Comment: That is correct. My mistake...

Answer (score 0):

When I go to:
`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&type=post`

I get 
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "100002667502867_210058145759767",
         "from": {
            "name": "Alessio Diesse",
            "id": "100002667502867"
         },
         "message": "I just redeemed this deal! Check it out: http://www.google.com",
         "type": "status",
         "application": {
            "name": "SpotOnCo App",
            "canvas_name": "spotonco-app",
            "namespace": "spotonco-app",
            "id": "132159653549822"
         },
         "created_time": "2012-02-12T00:53:28+0000",
         "updated_time": "2012-02-12T00:53:28+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "100001565919790_296841673711361",
         "from": {
            "name": "Victor Asuquo",
            "id": "100001565919790"
         },
         "message": "\u003Ca href=\"http://www.google.com\"> click here to click here \u003C/a>",
         "type": "status",
         "application": {
            "name": "BlackBerry",
            "canvas_name": "viabberry",
            "namespace": "viabberry",
            "id": "111498688870155"
         },
         "created_time": "2012-02-11T23:46:43+0000",
         "updated_time": "2012-02-11T23:46:43+0000"
      },
      ...

When I go to the same link **adding an access token**, I get:

{
  "data": [
  ]
}

So the moral of the story here is: don't add &access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN to the query and you'll be accessing public data.  ;)

Comment: Thank you for explanation. However, I noticed that I can get results only for old links. I looked for URL, that was shared by me and my friends a week ago, but Facebook Search shows no results...

Comment: What's the link to your post that you cannot search for?